# Why is the customers email address not sending to Stripe?

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I have a simple custom button Stripe Checkout setup at the moment which is charging payments ok but I cannot seem to get the customers email address to pass back to Stripe.

Heres my current code:

**JS**

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'myPublicKey',
    image: '/images/RoadPreview.jpg',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token, args){
        $form.append(jQuery('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token.id));
        $form.append(jQuery('<input type="hidden" name="stripeEmail" />').val(token.email));
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
});

jQuery('#roadFlow').on('click', function(e) {  
    var token = function(res){
        var $input = jQuery('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
        jQuery('form').append($input).submit();
    };

    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
        name: 'Road Bike - Flow',
        description: 'Make a £500 deposit to Order Now',
        billingAddress: true,
        shippingAddress: true,
        currency: "gbp",
        amount: 50000,
        token: token
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    require_once('stripeConfig.php');

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("mySecretKey");
    $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $email = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        'id' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'card'  => $token
    ));

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'amount'   => 50000,
        'description' => "Dassi Road - Flow",
        "receipt_email" => $email,
        'currency' => 'gbp'
    ));
    echo '<h1>Successfully Paid!</h1>';
?>
```

**Button**

```
<form action="charge.php" method="post"><button type="submit" id="roadFlow">Order Now</button>
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Not clear which step is problem or how you get email to send to stripe to create token

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the `token` callback that you defined in the `StripeCheckout.configure()` call when you call `handler.open()`, and the overriding function does not add the `stripeEmail` field.

This should work:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'myPublicKey',
    image: '/images/RoadPreview.jpg',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token, args){
        $form.append(jQuery('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token.id));
        $form.append(jQuery('<input type="hidden" name="stripeEmail" />').val(token.email));
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
});

jQuery('#roadFlow').on('click', function(e) {  
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
        name: 'Road Bike - Flow',
        description: 'Make a £500 deposit to Order Now',
        billingAddress: true,
        shippingAddress: true,
        currency: "gbp",
        amount: 50000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ywain, I've taken these overrides out but now get the following error... Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\Card' with message 'Cannot charge a customer that has no active card'